# match everything before and match everything after a certain character

Tags: javascript, regex

I need one regex to match everything before and one to match everything after a certain character, like a colon.

```
 foo:bar
```

Something to match 'foo' and something to match 'bar'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't use regexes for that. Use [split](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp).

Comment: `split` will fail if the value has a `:`.

Comment: It won't return the entire value.

Comment: @SLaks you have to provide also the `":"` argument to `split` :)

Comment: What SLaks is trying to say is, if the part of the string after `:` also contains a colon the result will contain 3 substrings.  This doesn't fit the question's criteria of, *"I need one regex to match everything before and one to match **everything after a certain character**, like a colon"*.  However, it's likely that the OP specified that requirement with a little naivety and `split` is good enough for him :-)

Answer (score 3):

In regex you are able to define groups (by parentheses).

```
"foo:bar".match(/(.*?):(.*)/) // -> ["foo:bar", "foo", "bar"]
//                               whole regexp, 1st group, 2nd group
```

`.*?` in first group means *non-greedy* version of `.*`, which prevents eating all of the string by it (matching as less as possible `.`'s)

(which really does not matter in this case, but matters when you'll be matching e.g. "foo:bar:spam")

Answer (score 2):

You don't need regular expressions here.

```
var middle = str.indexOf(':');
var key = str.substr(0, middle);
var value = str.substr(middle + 1);
```

If you do want to use regular expressions, you can do it like this:

```
var matches = /([^:]+):(.+)/.exec(str);

var key = matches[1];
var value = matches[2];
```

Comment: +1 for meeting the criteria of everything before and everything after the colon :-)

Answer (score 1):

These two should do it:

```
'foo:bar'.match(/(.*):/)
'foo:bar'.match(/:(.*)/)
```

Will there be more than one ":" in the string? If so, you'd probably prefer this one:

```
'foo:bar'.match(/(.*?):/)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a regexp instead of str.split, you can use:

```
var str="foo:bar";
var pattern=/([^:]+):([^:]+)/gi;
var arr=pattern.exec(str);
arr.shift();
```

Now arr will be an array of two elements: ['foo', 'bar'].

Answer (score 1):

You want look-ahead, and look-behind. Which match stuff followed by, or preceded by a certain character, without including that character in the match.

For look-ahead, you'd have something like .*(?=:)  , which means any character, 0 or more times, followed by a colon, but don't include the colon in the match,

For look-behind, you have  .*(?<=:)   , which means any character 0 or more times, preceded by a colon, but don't include the colon in the match. The trick here is that the look-behind expression comes AFTER the rest, which can seem counter intuitive, because you're looking for a colon that comes before, but it's because any regex really returns a position, and you want the colon to come right before that position.